# Pandas showing wrong datetime format in seaborn plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, seaborn

I have a problem to show datetime format in seaborn.

Here is my dataframe shown below

```
Country     Date        Count_1  Count_2 Count_3
Australia   2020-01-22      0       0       0
Canada      2020-01-22      2       1       3
...         ...             ...     ..       ...
```

I changed the format of Date as shown below.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.rename(columns={'Date': 'Day_Date'}, inplace=True)
```

When I draw a seaborn graph, `Day_date` cannot be intended format.
Its format is shown `2020-01-22T00:00:00.000000000`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1:]).date.tolist()
```